# Keeping Server Side Files Up-To-Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, file-upload, file

Is there a built in way to automatically synchronize sharepoint hosted files with an external files (update on a daily-basis preferably)? The only way I know of is dragging the files into the site through SharePoint Designer, I really have no idea where to begin with this - I know workflows can be used to move data around - any help would be appreciate. In case it matters the file in question will probably be a .txt, or some other flat file.

Thanks in advance.